# Retrieving data from an API for a component's data source

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to retrieve data from an API using an existing node package called `pokeapi-js-wrapper`. I'm a bit new to Angular, so I'm not sure if I'm approaching this correctly. I've built the service out as follows (the data itself is placeholder).

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Pokedex } from "pokeapi-js-wrapper";
import { Pokemon } from 'src/Pokemon';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PokeApiService {

  api: Pokedex;
  pokemon: Pokemon[];

  constructor() {
    this.api = new Pokedex();
  }

  getAllPokemon() {
    console.log("all pokemon", this.pokemon); //PROBLEM #1
    return this.api.getPokemonsList().then((response) => {
      this.pokemon.push(response.results.map(p => {
        return {
          name: p.name,
          number: 0,
          evolutionLink: "#",
          movesetLink: "#"
        } as Pokemon;
      }));
    });
  }
}
```

I have 2 problems I run into at this point, possibly related.

Problem #1: `this.pokemon` doesn't work. Am I forgetting the scope of `this` in this area? The `console.log` I've included has the output `all pokemon undefined`. What am I doing wrong here?

Problem #2: How can I retrieve this data for use in my component? I've defined the component as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Pokemon } from 'src/Pokemon';
import { PokeApiService } from 'src/app/poke-api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pokemon-list',
  templateUrl: './pokemon-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pokemon-list.component.css']
})
export class PokemonListComponent implements OnInit {

  pokemon: Pokemon[] = [];
  columnsToDisplay: string[] = ["number", "name", "moveset-link", "evolution-info"];

  constructor(private pokeApiService: PokeApiService) {
    pokeApiService.getAllPokemon().then(function (response) {
      this.pokemon = response; //PROBLEM #2
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

When getting the response from the service, will I be able to just set it to the data source for my table? For extra context, I'm using Angular Material and the template is defined as follows:

```
<h1>Pokémon List</h1>

<table mat-table [dataSource]="pokemon" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay"></tr>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="number">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Number </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let pokemon"> {{pokemon.number}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let pokemon"> {{pokemon.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="moveset-link">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Moveset Info </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let pokemon"> <a mat-stroked-button color="primary"
                [href]="pokemon.movesetLink">Moveset</a> </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="evolution-info">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Evolution Info </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let pokemon"> <a mat-stroked-button color="primary"
                [href]="pokemon.evolutionLink">Evolution Info</a></td>
    </ng-container>
</table>
```

Comment: You are declaring the Pokemon array, but you need to instantiate it in the constructor. this.Pokemon = new Array<Pokemon>(). After that, you can push values into the array.

Comment: For #2, if the response is indeed an array of Pokemon, it will be available in your template. You should try iterating the result set first before using a material component. *ngFor="let p of Pokemon".

Answer (score 0):

For #1: you need not only to declare the type of class property but also assign value / initialize it. Declared variable remains undefined since its undefined.

```
export class PokeApiService {

  api: Pokedex;
  pokemon: Pokemon[]; // this only declares the type but no value is assigned

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pokemon = []; // init the property with empty array value;
    this.api = new Pokedex();
  }

}
```

You can init values inside constructor or inside relevant Angular component lifecycle hook (such as ngOnInit)

#2: Problem occurs since you are using unnamed function that creates its own execution scope (and 'this') and this.pokemon line attempts to find 'pokemon' variable inside that execution scope. To fix you need to use arrow function like below, arrow functions do not create their own execution scope and 'transparently' can access outer execution scope (in this case the class that contains 'pokemon':

```
  constructor(private pokeApiService: PokeApiService) {
    pokeApiService.getAllPokemon().then((response) => { // use arrow function to prevent this.pokemon pointing at the unnamed function scope;
      this.pokemon = response;
    });
  }
```